# spark share cached memory between different jobs in same context

Tags: apache-spark, caching, persist

In spark job server, we can create a context and shared this context between different jobs. Currently I want to run same job multiple times in one context, my question is can I load the data at first time and cache or persist in memory, for next time I just load form memory.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I find out a way as follow:

```
if (spark.sparkContext.getPersistentRDDs.isEmpty) {
      ts.createOrReplaceTempView(tableName)
      spark.sqlContext.cacheTable(tableName)
}
```

currently, the question is how can i check the date of the cached data? If I can get the date I then can replace the cached data according to the date.